# How do I iterate through Associations in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, iteration

Ok, So I have a review model, and a votes model (Upvotes and Downvotes modeled through a single variable 'likes', If its true its an upvote, if its false its a downvote.). The votes are a has_many relation, and are polymorphic (I hope to be able to use this on more than just reviews later on).

So in the reviews model has the line

```
 has_many :votes, :as => :votable
```

And the votes model is defined like this

```
class Vote < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :votable, :polymorphic => true
  belongs_to :user

  def upvote?
    like
  end

  def downvote?
    !like
  end
end
```

Now this is fine, I can upvote, downvote and remove votes just fine. But I'm trying to generate a score bassed on the upvotes and downvotes (Simply upvotes-downvotes for now).
To do this I added the following to the reviews model

```
def score
  up = 0
  down = 0
  self.votes.each do |v|
    if v.upvote?
      up += 1
    elsif v.downvote?
      down += 1
    end
  end
  up-down
end
```

However I always get 0 back as the answer. The error is in the loop, as I can set the up or down variables to be what ever outside of it and they are passed through. Its starting to drive me insane, and I have no idea where im going wrong.

Comment: what is the relation of the review model to users/votes?

Comment: The relation is `has_many :votes, dependent: :destroy` There are also methods in the user model which create and destroy votes, check to see if they user has voted for a review, and check to see HOW they voted (using the upvote? and downvote? methods in vote)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are sure the error is in the loop then here's my best guess:

you have v.upvote? as an if, and v.downvote? as an elsif.

What happens if both of these are false?  I am pretty sure nothing will happen.  And therefore, 0 - 0 = 0 and you always get zero back.  The loop is perfectly fine, if your v.upvote? and v.downvote? are written correctly, or they are the correct values to begin with.

Try:

```
if v.upvote?
 ...
else
 ...
end
```

Obviously you have those setup in that way for a reason, but you are possibly just zoning in on the wrong thing.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Ah, I didn't think of that, But in this case, I know that they are true (I set them in the DB for testing). And they are used when deciding which partial to display for the upvote/downvote forms. I think its the loop because if I add to the variables on each loop (Not inside the if block) they still return 0. Which says to me that `self.votes.each` isn't working as I would have expected

Comment: A way to test it would be setup your loop as you originally had it, except add a variable at the top: counter = 0   Then in the loop add an else and increment the counter in the else block.  Then after the loop do logger.debug(counter) to see how many times the loop is iterating without touching on up and down.  Verify other things you'd like to know using logger.debug inside the loop but outside the if block to figure out what v is per iteration.  I am fairly sure you have written the loop exactly the way you should've.  Something strange is going on.

Comment: Ohh, Nice, I didn't know about logger.debug! Thanks, Im sure I shall give that a go now! Hope fully it helps :D

Comment: I found the error! For some reason the votable_type wasn't being set correctly, so when doing self.votes it finds no votes. DOH! Thanks for the help Ben :)

Answer (score 1):

For starters it might be best to use the database to count the number of down and upvotes with a named scope.

Then once you have the total counts, you can subtract downvotes from upvotes.

For more info on scopes see: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes